# make "No Result Found" appear. JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, web

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#searchme").keyup(function(){

if( $(this).val() != "")
{$("#searchTbl tbody>tr").hide();

$("#searchTbl td:contains-ci('" + $(this).val() + "')").parent("tr").show()  ;} 
else{
$("#searchTbl tbody>tr").show();
  
}});
```

I need to show "no results found" PLEASE HELP i'm using javascript. #searchtbl is the name of the table. my table looks like when you type a single letter/word/number that is alike with a given data, all data with that value pops and data who's not match hides.. my problem is. it does not show "No result found" when there's no alike. thanks for the help.

Comment: your question is not clear. can you please provide some details?

Comment: i'm using javascript. #searchtbl is the name of the table. my table looks like when you type a single letter/word/number that is alike with a given data, all data with that value pops and data who's not match hides.. my problem is. it does not show "No result found" when there's no alike. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if( $(this).val() != "")
 {
     $("#searchTbl tbody>tr").hide();
     var search = $("#searchTbl td:contains-ci('" + $(this).val()+ "')");
     if ( search.length == 0 )
     {
          alert("No results"); //replace with your own message inside an element
     }
     else
     {
        search.parent("tr").show()  ;
     }
  } 
  else
  {
      $("#searchTbl tbody>tr").show();
  }
```

Replace your `IF/ELSE`-clause with this. It will test if any elements where returned, if not show message.

jQuery's selector function returns an array. If the array is has a length of `0` no element was found that matched the selector.